# Real time metrics in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, metrics, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to use external metrics system to monitor stream progress in spark. For this I should send notifications with metrics as soon as possible (number of read, transformed and written records)

`StreamExecution` uses `ProgressReporter` to send `QueryProgressEvents` with statistics (numInputRows, processedRowsPerSecond etc) to `StreamingQueryListener`. The problem is it happens when all data in batch are processed. However I would like to get a notification with the number of input rows as soon as they read from source (before transformation and write happens) and then number written records when data sent to a sink.

Is there a way to get such kind of metrics per batch in structured streaming in real time?

Answer (score 2):

Metrics for structured streaming are not currently implemented out of the box anywhere besides the databricks platform. The only way to get them via open source spark is to extend the streaming query listener class and write your own.

Comment: It won't work. Events in streaming query listener doesn't have much information of what's happening in a stream. It's possible to get number of input rows only on query progress but it happens when the batch is completely processed.

Comment: Theyre available in the class:org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent

Comment: There is one more way to get the number of input row quicker - through SparkListenerInterface for each job. But if I have multiple streams running then there is no way to know to which stream the job is related. And still no way to get number of written records [output metrics are incorrect](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23288)

Comment: Sure they are available and I know about `StreamingQueryListener` (see my question) but there are 2 problems:
1. No metrics about number of written records
2. Event happens when a batch is completely processed (read, transformed and written to a sink) but not at the moment when action happens (ie. event with number of input rows immediately after reading from data source)